# Where would I ask about the cause of a recent political themed blip on my website?

Tags: discussion, scope, specific-question

Politics.SE seems like the obvious place for this question, since the underlying topic is political in nature, but I think it's almost as obvious that it would be off-topic on the site.

I have a web page that provides a summary of Theodore Kaczynski's "*Industrial Society and its Future*" thesis.
Google reports that its impressions and clicks are fairly consistent over time, but on June 14 queries for "*Unabomber manifesto summary*" spiked to ten times the normal rate:
[image]

If it had been that one day only, I'd ignore it as a mistake, but it took nearly a week for it to return to normal after that, so they were likely real queries.

I'm curious about what happened that day to cause this unusual activity.

But where could I ask about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Questions about where to ask a question are generally asked on [Big Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com), but I really don't think there's any place to ask this here, at least without any more information.

- One of the technical sites might allow questions about how to use Google Reports to get information on these visits.
- If you find some political link that you don't understand (for example, people are coming to your site with the query *"Unabomber Bob Dole"*, then you might be able to ask here about why Bob Dole is (hypothetically) quoting the Unabomber.

Questions on this site, however, need to be *political questions*, or at least directly about politics. The fact that a question is references something related to politics isn't enough to make it on-topic